# displaying snowflake data as drop downs in a table in streamlit

Tags: pandas, dataframe, drop-down-menu, streamlit

I am trying to build a streamlit app that connects to a snowflake table, fetches data and displays as editable table in streamlit and writes back the edited info back to snowflake, I am able to get this until here. However, I want to display couple of columns to show as drop down to show values in those columns. Table that I intend to bring is a mapping table and last two columns needs to be provide all the column values as drop down, here is the sample file which explains what I am looking for

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. here is my code for first piece.

   import pandas as pd import json import streamlit as st from
   snowflake.snowpark import Session

   if 'snowflake_connection' not in st.session_state:

   ```
   # connect to Snowflake using the creds in json

   with open('creds.json') as f:
       connection_parameters = json.load(f)
   st.session_state.snowflake_connection = \
       Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
   session = st.session_state.snowflake_connection else:
   session = st.session_state.snowflake_connection
   ```

   st.set_page_config(layout='centered', page_title='Data Editor',
   page_icon='\xf0\x9f\xa7\xae') st.title('Column Mapping Editor \xe2\x9d\x84\xef\xb8\x8f')

   ## Using object notation

   add_selectbox = 
   st.sidebar.selectbox('Select the Table you would like to Map',
   ('Member', 'Account', 'Transactions'))

   def get_dataset():

   ```
   # load messages df

   df = session.table('FIELD_MAPPING_CONFIG')

   return df
   ```

   dataset = get_dataset()

   with st.form('data_editor_form'):
   st.caption('Update the Column Mappings....')
   edited = st.data_editor(dataset, use_container_width=True,
   num_rows='dynamic')
   submit_button = st.form_submit_button('Submit')

   if submit_button:
   try:

   ```
       # Note the quote_identifiers argument for case insensitivity

       session.write_pandas(edited, 'FIELD_MAPPING_CONFIG',
                            overwrite=True, quote_identifiers=False)
       st.write('Mapping Table updated Sucessfully!')
       st.success('Mapping Table updated Sucessfully!')
   except:

       # time.sleep(5)

       st.warning('Error updating table')
       st.experimental_rerun()
   ```